# I try to find the successor of a key in a binary search tree in time O(1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

yes i have to say this is some kind of homework and I am not expecting to get the answer but i have no clue how to proceed here.

I know how to find out the successor and predecessor in several ways but none of them working in time complexety O(1).

The excercise says that we can save more infomration at each node. However, the insert and delete functionallity should be constand at a time complexety of O(h) where h is the heigth of the tree.

My first and easy to implement idea was to save in each node how many left and rigth nodes this one have. So i just have to change the insert and delete method everytime a node is passed to increment or decrease these variables for each node. But i have no clue how this information can beat  the time complexity to O(1).

Comment: how about remembering successor nodes when inserting and then retrieving this information? Something like `insert(node) {... node.parentNode = parentNode}, getParentNode(node) { return node.parentNode}`

Comment: Look for the threaded binary tree approach

Comment: this is an old question, but finding the successor of a binary search tree (with parent pointers, which most BST implementations use) is *already* `O(1)` in *amortized* time.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to be able to find the predecessors and successors in O(1) time, then you can link the nodes into a doubly linked list in addition to linking them into a BST.

This doesn't change the complexity of the insert operation, since you will find a new node's successor and predecessor during the normal insert procedure.  You just have to remember them so you can use them when you link everything together.

Note that even without the extra links (assuming you have parent links), then finding the successor or predecessor of a node takes constant time *on average*, even though it takes O(log N) time in the worst case.  For this reason, extra links to successors and predecessors are not often used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a flawed exercise to me. Traversing up to the required key from root takes O(h) time so the solution to find successor to a key would take O(h) + time to find successor.

Ignoring this fact, say if you were to be at the required key node magically, the only way you can achieve O(1) time is to store the successor and predecessor for all nodes beforehand. The insertion and deletion clue is for this i.e. everytime you insert a node or delete from the tree, you will need to recalculate successor and predecessor for all nodes.

Update: As Yves pointed out in comment, successor will only be updated for certain node

Comment: Not for all nodes, just for the two immediate neighbors.

Comment: Indeed, not all nodes need to be updated. However, I did not understand what you mean by two immediate neighbors. For insertion, if you look at this [example](http://flylib.com/books/2/264/1/html/2/images/fig21-17.jpg) , if one were to add 32 to the tree, 30 would need to be updated. If the inserted node is right child node, parent will be updated. If the inserted node is left child, we need to travel up the tree and find the lowest ancestor that has the node insertion in its right subtree.

Comment: You only need to adapt hte successro/predecessorlinks of two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!** Can be done. But use O(n) extra space.

Traverse the tree and store successor information into a `map (or hashmap)`. where `key` will be current node's value and `value` will be successor node's value. This will use `O(n)` space but time complexity to answer your query will be always `O(1)`.